# pip + Nexus + virtualenv = HTTP read timeout error

Tags: python, caching, pip, virtualenv, nexus

We've started using Nexus to host an internal Python repository of our projects.  It works well, except there is a strange problem in virtualenvs.

We configured pip by adding a pip.conf file with the following text:

```
[global]
index = https://username:password@nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-all/pypi
index-url = https://username:password@nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-all/simple
```

This works:

```
pip install pandas
```

We can also install our own packages that we've uploaded to Nexus.

However, this fails:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate 
pip install pandas
```

The error is here:

```
(snip)
File "/home/pteehan/venv3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 246, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nexus.(our_company).com',    port=443): Read timed out.
```

The same error occurs for nearly any package - it fails at the 'Collecting' stage after a few seconds.  Increasing the timeout length did not help.  Through trial and error we discovered that clearing pip's cache solves the problem.  So again from inside the virtualenv, this works:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir pandas
```

Any idea what's going on? It seems that pip is getting stuck on the cache when using virtualenvs.

Answer (score 1):

We never solved this problem, but there is a clean workaround.  Place the following line in your pip.conf:

```
no-cache-dir = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we had the same issue and found out that the problem is coming from our pip client configuration and especially the default timeout used within pip (based on urllib3 that based itself upon the builtin socket library that use a 15 seconds timeout).

You can solve it by adding the following line in your pip.conf:

```
timeout = 300
```